# Is this really a function IDA could not decode?

Tags: ida

I have the following IDA output:

```
BEGTEXT:00415A2C read_dpc_sub_415928 endp
BEGTEXT:00415A2C
BEGTEXT:00415A2C ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGTEXT:00415A2D                 align 10h
BEGTEXT:00415A30                 push    ebx
BEGTEXT:00415A31                 push    edx
BEGTEXT:00415A32                 mov     edx, eax
BEGTEXT:00415A34                 call    sub_41576C
BEGTEXT:00415A39                 mov     ebx, eax
BEGTEXT:00415A3B                 call    sub_415758
BEGTEXT:00415A40                 mov     eax, ebx
BEGTEXT:00415A42                 call    sub_4158C8
BEGTEXT:00415A47                 mov     eax, ebx
BEGTEXT:00415A49                 pop     edx
BEGTEXT:00415A4A                 pop     ebx
BEGTEXT:00415A4B                 retn
BEGTEXT:00415A4B ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, IDA has considered that this is a code block but it hasn't been made a function.

**Can you explain how one should try handle this situation ?**

i.e. is this really code in the end and what to consider when making a function.

(if that matters, the executable is a 32-bit Windows one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make it a function by placing a cursor to address 00415A2C in disassembly view and pressing <kbd>P</kbd>. If this doesn't work you can select the whole function and, again, press <kbd>P</kbd>. The documentation on this action is located [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/484.shtml). If all this doesn't work, undefine `align 10h` by pressing <kbd>U</kbd>, make resulting bytes code by pressing <kbd>C</kbd> and try again.

There are a lot of reasons why this function has not been created automatically, including, but not limited by:

- This function is not called directly
- This function is not called at all
- IDA autoanalysis was unable to find a reference to this function as function

Comment: I will assume that IDA is right for the time being, then I will eventually dig deeper with the first two reasons you've written, thanks!

Comment: Why undefining the align may solve the issue?

Comment: I think that I remember something like this on older IDA versions: align was not recognized as instruction and thus the function couldn't be created. I really don't remember in which architecture and in which version I had seen it.